# How to make stick person like Japanese samurai

Tags: modeling, extrude

I want to make stick person like this image.

But I don't know how to make his back hair (not top hair=chonmage).

I thought, make UV Sphere and extrude  back hair part.
Then I realized, I can't extrude in a curved shape.
So.. Please teach me; ;

Blender 2.9.2
Windows 10
[image]

[image]

Comment: "Then I realized, I can't extrude in a curved shape", what do you mean by that? Maybe you want to extrude along normals, (alt e > extrude along normals)

Comment: @Alexbries 
Sorry for bmy bad English. That's not what I want to do.I can't make a smooth curve because the surface is square. (Please take a look at the added image)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the sphere, then create a different object (i.e. a plane), use the face snap option (project individual elements) and model the hair snapping every vertex to the underlying sphere.

Then add a mirror modifier for the back of the head, a solidify modifier to get thikness, and a subsurf.

[image]

Comment: Omg Thank you so much!
Did you make under 30 minute! wonderful...!

But I wan to ask you more...
I did snap plane to sphere but it's not perfect.(please take look at added image)
So should I fix it by moving the dots one by one in edit mode?

And I want to ask you how to make a beautiful curve from a straight line?
(Around the ears and around the neckline)

Comment: I can't add image so please take look at image from this URL 
https://ibb.co/GFL5ZRs

Comment: Yes, moving and extruding vertices one by one in edit mode with face snap enabled will force them to snap to the sphere. Then a simple subsurf modifier (in my example level 2) will transform jagged lines into sweet curves.

Comment: Helol Josh, finally I completed thanks to you!
https://ibb.co/5k26MCr

Comment: Very nice! You're Welcome.